# Inserir em mysql com php e função ajax

Tags: javascript

Criei os campos a serem preenchidos com o seguinte html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-pt">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Código de Barras</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container shadowbox" style="width:700px;">  
   <h3 align="center"><strong>Registo de Atividades Diárias</strong></h3>  
   <br />  
</div>
<div> 
<input type="text" id="codigo" name="codigo" value="<?= $_GET['codigo'] ?>" />  
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="IniciarTarefa" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<button type="button" id="IniciarTarefa" name="IniciarTarefa" class="btn btn-info" onclick="myFunction()">Iniciar Tarefa</button>
</div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="IniciarTarefa1" name="IniciarTarefa"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Colaborador" id="Colaborador" value="xxxxxx">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="PequenoAlmoco" id="acao"></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<input type="hidden" id="PequenoAlmoco" name="tarefa" value="Pequeno Almoço">
</div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="inserir_registo()">Pequeno Almoço</button>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
document.getElementById("IniciarTarefa1").value = dateTime;
}

function inserir_registo()
{

    var dadosajax = {
        'codigo' : $("#codigo").val(),
        'IniciarTarefa1' : $("#IniciarTarefa1").val(),
            'Colaborador' : $("#Colaborador").val(),
        'PequenoAlmoco' : $("#PequenoAlmoco").val()
    };
    pageurl = './conexaoteste';
    $.ajax({
        url: pageurl,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        error: function(){
            alert('Erro: Inserir Registo!!');
        },
        success: function(result)
        { 
            if($.trim(result) == '1')
            {
                alert("O seu registo foi inserido com sucesso!");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Ocorreu um erro ao inserir o seu registo!");
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Mas quando vou a inserir na base de dados recebo o seguinte erro na consola:

> teste2?preview=true:363 Uncaught ReferenceError: inserir_registo is
>   not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

php:

```
$codigo = $_REQUEST["codigo"]; 
$IniciarTarefa = $_REQUEST["IniciarTarefa"];
$tarefa = $_REQUEST["tarefa"];
$Colaborador = $_REQUEST["Colaborador"];    

try
    {
$sql = "INSERT INTO teste (`codigo`, `IniciarTarefa`, `tarefa`, `FimTarefa`, `Colaborador`)
VALUES ('".trim($codigo)."', '".trim($IniciarTarefa)."', '".trim($tarefa)."', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', '".trim($Colaborador)."')";

$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);

echo "1";
    } 
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {

        echo "0";
    }
```

Comment: parece que nem carregou o arquivo com a função, é um arquivo separado do html? está incluido no header?

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual a função está no mesmo arquivo do HTML e está a seguir ao HTML, não está no header da página, mas tem de estar?

Comment: Iae, Bruno. Este erro é retornado quando a função não foi carregada. Tem como [edit] a pergunta e postar o seu HTML com o script incorporado, como vc mencionou? Repare que nem aqui no site ele está retornando esse erro... Como tá sua tag `script`?

Comment: @LipESprY editei a pergunta com o código exatamente como se encontra na minha página

Comment: Aqui funcionou normalmente **após adicionar a lib jQuery**: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>`. Coloquei ela dentro do `head`. Teste aí.

Comment: não precisa estar no `head`, mas é uma boa prática colocar os scripts antes, a não ser que queira que ele execute ao final, mas também falta a referência para o `jQuery`, como o @LipESprY comentou

Comment: Só não concordo com essa afirmação: "mas é uma boa prática colocar os scripts antes". O ideal é colocar conforme a ordem de uso e requisito. Colocar uma lib que só vai ter uso "mediante ação do usuário" antes de carregar o HTML só vai atrasar a renderização do HTML. Sempre respeitando os requisitos: se um script precisa do jQuery, ele deve vir depois do jQuery... kk

Comment: @LipESprY adicionei a biblioteca e alterei a ordem do `JavaScript` e já não retornou o erro, mas recebo a mensagem de registo na base de dados com sucesso, mas não está a inserir na tabela da base de dados.

Comment: Acontece que tem muito erro no seu código. Isso torna a pergunta "ampla". Começando pela parte de que o seu ajax não está enviando os dados na requisição... Você definiu a variável `dadosajax`, mas o ajax não a envia ao PHP...

Comment: @LipESprY dentro da variável `dadosajax`só está a enviar o `value` do `input` com o `id="pequenoalmoco"`. Os erros estão dentro do `ajax` ou no HTML

Comment: Você precisa colocar os dados no ajax: `data: dadosajax, ...`

Comment: @LipESprY, quer dizer que acha bom ir colocando scripts no meio do html? A melhor opção seria um arquivo externo, porque ainda pode se beneficiar do cache ao carregar no navegador, agora se vai por inline no documento, seria melhor organizar tudo no head, ou como eu mencionei, por ao final o que pode ser carregado após a carga.

Comment: @Ricardo Considero "**bom**" carregar os scripts sempre por último (no final do DOM), mas alguns são **necessários** antes. Seja no corpo ou no cabeçalho (`head`). É uma questão de otimização. O mesmo vale para imagens. Pode-se colocar uma thumbnail na `src` e um atributo `data-img`. Daí quando terminar de carregar o DOM, você vai renderizando as imagens originais pegando do `data-img`. Tudo isso é questão de otimização. Não quer dizer que TEM que ser assim. Você pode carregar seus scripts no cabeçalho tranquilo. Mas talvez possa gerar um belo de um atraso "na primeira renderização... 

Comment: @LipESprY Obrigado pelas dicas, já corrigi os erros que tinha no meu código, tanto em `HTML` como `ajax` e já funciona como pretendia